# objective-c Bridging header not found in swift compiler-code generation

Tags: ios, swift3

I am doing an ios app  in swift 3. And I want to add `ARKit`which is available in `objective-c`. I dragged all objective-c files into my project then it asked to create bridging header. So I let it to create. And I imported all objective-c`.h` files inside that like this.

[image]

But when I try to build its showing 22 number of issues like `UIView`cannot identify etc..

Then I tried to add the `bridging header`path to build settings under `swift compiler - code generation`. But I dont see `objective-c Bridging header`section under that.

[image]

[image]

Please help me. What can I do to add these objective-c files into my swift 3 project successfully.
Thanks

Comment: What kinds of errors do you get?

Answer (score 2):

The Objective-C bridging header setting can be found under `Swift Compiler - General` under `Build Settings`.

But I like to add the bridging header by having Xcode generate it for me. I add a junk Objective-C class by `File > New > File...` and it will ask me if I want to add a bridging header to my project.

If you do that, you'll only need to move whatever you have in your bridging header now to that one and delete the header you have now. The header will be set properly in the project's settings.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your build setting is selected as "**All**" and "**Combined**" look at below link

[Swift Compiler - General is missing in Xcode 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473381/swift-compiler-general-is-missing-in-xcode-9-1)