# Swift Compiler - General is missing in Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bridging-header, xcode9.1

I was trying give bridging header in **target** -> **Build settings** -> **Objective C Bridging header**

I could able to do that using project created using **Xcode 9**

[image]

But I couldn't find **Objective C Bridging header** in **Xcode 9.1**. It is missing in project created in Xcode 9.1 like below.

[image]

Comment: @iPatel tried but not found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43983516/6898523

Comment: @V12 my issue already solved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your build setting is selected as **"All"** and **"Combined"** look at below image

[image]

Click on above image for more clear. and just search **"bridg"** in search bar you will be see **Objective C Bridging header**.

Comment: Yes I got it. It was my mistake. Thanks